# Can we make an approach to install a software directly from internet

Tags: installation, windows-installer

Can we make an approach to install a software directly from internet, so that no need to give Software file to customer.

Comment: Can I ask, did I answer you question?  Or, if you elaborate it a little perhaps I can help.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest trying ClickOnce - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce.